# ExtJs 6.0 - Javascript event handler function scope inside Ext.application

Tags: javascript, extjs, event-handling, dom-events, extjs6

I do not understand how I can make the event handler function named `some_function()` get called:

```
var some_app = Ext.application({
  name   : 'some_app_name',
  launch : function() {
      function some_function(){
          Ext.toast('some_function called!');
      };
      var some_panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
          html:"Some <span onmouseover='some_function()'>text</span> with "+
               "a html-span that should"+
               " listen to mouseover events"
      });
      var some_viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
          items: [some_panel],
          renderTo : Ext.getBody()
      });
  }
});
```

Here is the corresponding Sencha Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/135r

**So the question is basically: What do I have to do in order to call `some_function()`?**

---

Note:

When I execute the Fiddle in my browser I can see that it gives me this error in the Browser-console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: span_onmouseover_event_handler is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline event handlers are executed in the global scope.  The *"function is not defined"* error is self-explanatory - your handler exists only in the local scope of application `launch` function.  There isn't a nice way to bind context to an inline declaration but if you insist on this style you can at least avoid polluting the global scope by declaring the handler as a member variable of the application:

```js
var some_app = Ext.application({
    name: 'some_app_name',
    some_function: function(){
        Ext.toast('some_function called!');
    },
    // ...
});
```

Then it can be reference with it's fully qualified path like so:

```html
<span onmouseover="some_app_name.app.some_function()">
```

[**» fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/135t)

---

That said, it would be much cleaner if you gave your markup a `class` attribute and let [extjs](/questions/tagged/extjs) handle the event delegation as in general this will avoid potential code duplication and issues with scope.  For example you could declare your panel like this:

```js
var some_panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    html: "Some <span class='some_class'>text</span> with "+
          "a html-span that should"+
          " listen to mouseover events",
    listeners: {
        element: 'el',
        delegate: 'span.some_class',
        mouseover: some_function
    }
});
```

[**» fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/135u)